# Replace connection string in Scaffold-DbContext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to learn by doing and it has been a fun struggle so far :D

I've finally got my project to scaffold my DB but it populates a warning in the code.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263 for guidance on storing connection strings.
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=<servername>;Database=<databaseName>;Trusted_Connection=True");
            }
        }
```

I've tried to update it to use the "DefalutConnection" in my appsettings.json file but it doesn't recognize `Configuration`. I've imported the namespace `using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;` but that still doesn't resolve the issue.

I'm trying to get something akin to the following: `options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))`

Not sure which direction to go in resolving this. Is this a non-issue or am I missing adding something to get this to pull from appsettings.json?

My guess is that the DbCOntextOptionsBuilder doesn't have a method for `Configuration` and I would need to build it out myself... but I'm not sure how to do that either.

Thanks for your time/attention on this.

**Solution Shown to Assist Others, See Marked Answer Below**

*Error*
`Unable to create an object of type 'ProfileContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728`

add `public IConfiguration Configuration {get;}`

inject it in your constructor

```
public ContextDbName(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
```

update your OnConfiguring method

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263 for guidance on storing connection strings.
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to inject Configuration into your DbContext constructor.

Comment: Maybe I spoke too soon :/  I have tested it with this update and the original pattern. With the new update, I get this error when adding a migration `Unable to create an object of type 'ProfileContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728`

Answer (score 1):

Running with the original script, created by Scaffolding, in the newly created context file I ran into other issues regarding dependency injection. This got me thinking more about [Microsofts Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings#aspnet-core).

So I added an injection into my startup file for my newly created Context class and like magic, it worked :D

**Startup.cs**:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddDbContext<ProfileContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scaffold like this:

Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "This is the connectiostring" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Data/Entities -ContextDir Data -Context "This is the contextname" -NoOnConfiguring -f

For your case -NoOnConfiguring will prevent to create the code with connectionstring (optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer)

Comment: for -OutputDir and -ContextDir you can give another folder